# .addClass() to element nearby $(this) but outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, addclass

I have this:

```
<div class="mycontainer active">
    <a href="#" class="mylink">link</a>
</div>

<div class="mycontainer">
    <a href="#" class="mylink">link</a>
</div>
```

and I want to "move" the active class to the second container when i click on the link in it.

I tried with the following jQuery:

```
$('.mycontainer .mylink').on('click', function(){
    $(".active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().find(".mycontainer").addClass('active');
});
```

But this is not working, actually I don't know pretty much about Javascript/jQuery, what am I doing wrong?
Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use instead:

```
$('.mycontainer .mylink').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.mycontainer').addClass('active').siblings('.mycontainer.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

or:

```
 $(this).parent(".mycontainer").addClass('active');
```

instead. Because `$(this).parent()` already refers to the element you're looking for, and then with `find()` you're trying to find elements with class `mycontainer` inside of it which will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
$(this).parent().find(".mycontainer")
```

is finding the mycontainer div, then looking for .mycontainer inside it, when actually you are already there.

Try this instead:

```
$('.mycontainer .mylink').on('click', function(){
    $(".active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining how it's working, i didn't choose you answer just because on my case using just .parent() is not working bacause in my real project the div are containing more complex structure with other divs and such, but thanks again for the explanation it helps me to better understand where i made a mistake! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the active class on the link that is getting clicked...

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/LCaNP/

```
$('.mycontainer .mylink').on('click', function(){
    $('.mycontainer').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myContainer').toggleClass('active')
```

should do it.
It will remove the class where it is present and add where it is not.
Check out [.toggleclass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

So, the code would be -

```
$('.mycontainer .mylink').on('click', function(){
   $('.myContainer').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFsVb/)